# Prove the following sequence (given recurrence relation) is defined and converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

We are given a sequence

> $a_1=1,\ a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n^2+c}{2a_n}$ for all $n\geq 1\ (c>0)$

and we need to prove it's *defined* for all $n$ and *converges* (and to what value, but that's easy).

**My attempt**: I want to show that $a_n$ is bounded and thus is defined. I showed that for all $n\geq 2,\ a_n\geq \sqrt c$ (the limit of the sequence) so $a_n\geq \text{min}(1,\sqrt c)$, and I'm pretty sure $a_2=\frac{1+c}{2}$ is an upper bound, but I cannot show it really is/find another easier to prove upper bound.

I feel like I'm the the wrong direction, any help is welcomed!

Comment: Can you prove that this sequence decreases for $n\ge 2$?

Comment: Is it possible that you mean "sequence" rather than "series"?

Comment: I think you *must prove* $\;a_n\neq0\;$ for all indexes in order to prove it is defined. Boundedness and etc. will come later. Also, I guess $\;c>0\;$ ...?

Comment: What you need to prove it is well defined is [Dedekind's Recursion Theorem](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/recursive-functions/#3). See also the beginning of $\bf \large 1$ [here](http://dec59.ruk.cuni.cz/~kolmanv/Recursion.pdf).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can proof both statements here. And yes, I meant sequence.I thought of proving $a_n\neq 0$ prior of opening this but it's only intuative ins't it? (plus what I proved already is stronger)

Comment: For what it's worth, it seems that $$\forall n\in \mathbb N\left(a_n=\sqrt c\,\text{coth}\left(2^{n-1}\text{arctanh}(\sqrt c)\right)\right)_.$$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha already told me that, but this is just the beggining of Infinitesimal Calci.1 so it's not worth anything.

Comment: It is Newton's method applied to $f(x)=x^2-c$. We have $$ x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}=\frac{x^2+c}{2x}$$ and since $f(x)$ is a convex function, $a_n\to \sqrt{c}$ pretty fast.

Comment: It also is the [babylonian method for computing square roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{c}{x}\right)$ (I guess that $c>0$).

i) Note that if $x>0$ the $f(x)>0$, which means that $a_n>0$ (the sequence is well-defined).

ii) For $x>0$, $f(x)\leq x$ iff $x\geq \sqrt{c}$ (why),
which means that if $a_n\geq \sqrt{c}$ then $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)\leq a_n$.

iii) If $x\geq \sqrt{c}$ then $f(x)\geq \sqrt{c}$ (why?) which means that
if $a_n\geq \sqrt{c}$ then $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)\geq \sqrt{c}$.

Now $a_2=\frac{1+c}{2}\geq \sqrt{c}$, therefore, by ii) and iii), for $n\geq 2$, $a_n\in [\sqrt{c},a_2]$ and $a_n$ is decreasing.

Comment: I can prove that it's decreasing from $n=2$ and on, but I don't see how does this prove it's defined? (We assume this in the proof aswell)

Comment: @Theoniix See my edited answer.

Comment: @Theoniix $a_n\not=0$ because if $x>0$ then $f(x)>0$ (if $c>0$),

Comment: So I just use induction to show it's well defined (which I can do in my own way in which I proved the inequallity)?

Comment: @Theoniix Yes. Any more doubts?

Comment: I'm just composing the proof before pressing that green checkmark, somehow now I'm having trouble with proving the decracing property. My induction step is $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n^2+c}{2a_n}\geq \frac{2c}{2a_n}=\frac{c}{a_n}$ but if I try to move foward then I get that the right expression is SMALLER than $\sqrt c$.

Comment: @Theoniix Use (ii) and (iii) to show that if $a_n\in [\sqrt{c},a_2]$ then $a_{n+1}\in [\sqrt{c},a_n]\subset [\sqrt{c},a_2]$.

Comment: I'm talking about proving (iii), you can't know $f(x)\geq \sqrt c$ (the inductive step). $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x+\frac{c}{x})$ right? but we can't conclude anything from $\frac{c}{x}\leq \sqrt{c}$, only if it was $\geq$.

Comment: @Theoniix For $x>0$, $f(x)$ is always $\geq \sqrt{c}$ (it the minimum value of $f$ in $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: Even though I know calculus I'm not supposed to know anything about functions when it comes to what this question is about. Isn't there an algebric way to prove it for the naturals?

Comment: @Theoniix Yes. $f(x)\geq \sqrt{c}$ iff $x^2+c\geq 2x\sqrt{c}$ iff  $(x-\sqrt{c})^2\geq 0$.